# ArangoDB: Longest shortest path - not just distance

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to solve a problem of finding what is the actual longest shortest path in my graph. I am using `arangosh` function `_diameter` but it will only give me numerical value of what the diameter of graph is. I need to know what is the actual path. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The following AQL query returns the longest shortest path.

```
LET ids = UNION(
(FOR x IN vertices1 RETURN x),
(FOR x IN vertices2 RETURN x)
)
FOR source IN ids
  FOR target IN ids
    FILTER source._id < target._id
      LET path = (FOR v, e IN ANY SHORTEST_PATH source TO target GRAPH @graphName RETURN [v, e]) 
      /* ==> [ [source, null], [v1, source->v1], .... [ target, vn -> target] ] */
  SORT LENGTH(path) DESC
  LIMIT 1
 RETURN path
```

L. 1-4 store all vertices in one array by iterating through every vertex collection. In case you only use one vertex collection, you can remove these lines and replace "ids" with your vertex collection.

L. 5-8 calculate all combinations of shortest paths between the listed vertices and provide the path output in form of `[ [source, null], [v1, source->v1], .... [ target, vn -> target] ]`.

L.7 `FILTER source._id < target._id` should only be used in case you are using undirected edges with `ANY` since the path vertex1 -> vertex2 equals vertex2 -> vertex1 when no directions are used. Remove this line if you are using `INBOUND/OUTBOUND` directions instead.

L. 10-11 sort all paths in descending order (longest path at the beginning) and limit the result set to 1 object.

L. 12 finally returns the path of the longest shortest path.

This query is very costly though, iterating over all vertices twice and calculating the shortest path for each vertex pair results in O(n³ log n). Therefore this query can only be used for a small vertex set.